# Not understanding why $_POST isn't set after click on input button

Tags: php, forms, post

In the context of a form without a submit button, I am not understanding why the $_POST variable doesn't get set.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $view="blablabla";
?>
<form class="" method='POST' accept-charset="UTF-8" action='index.php'>
<p>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="60" name='article' id='article' WRAP=SOFT>
    <?php
      echo $view;
    ?>
  </textarea>
</p>    
<p>
  <input type="button" name='do1' id='do1' value="do 1"/>
  <input type="button" name='do2' id='do2' value="do 2"/>
</p>
</form>

<?php
  var_dump("POST :",$_POST);
?>
```

Shouldn't the var_dump show a value to $_POST once I click one of the 2 buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope- the input types have to be **submit** (`<input type="submit"/>`) for the form to be submitted. A POST request has to be sent to your PHP script in order for there to be any values populated in the $_POST array :)

EDIT: They don't *have* to be submit, but in the case of the code above, with no external triggers on the buttons, you'll need submit buttons :)

### For your multiple buttons issue:

If you're using JavaScript/Ajax to send the POST request to PHP on the button click, you'll need to do something similar:

```
if (isset($_POST['x'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
}
```

This is so the script doesn't return the HTML of the page (i.e. your form)- this isn't an issue if you're POSTing to another page :)

Below is some sample jQuery code to send some POST data on button click (not going to give you the exact code, you'll have to modify it to your needs!)

```
$('#my_button').click(function(){
    $.post('myfile.php', data, function(response) { //the var 'data' is the POST data you're sending
        // handle response here, the data being in the response variable 
    });
});
```

Comment: *"the input types have to be submit for the form to be submitted"* Who said the OP didn't attach event listeners to the buttons somewhere else?

Comment: See, now you're just being pedantic.

He is right, but with regards to the code ABOVE (i.e. no additional code you're using that you haven't shown us), you're going to need submit buttons :)

Comment: OK, that makes sense but I need to have several buttons and I don't want my user to have to click twice.  Is there a workaround, maybe by calling a JS function like `document.getElementById("xyz").submit();`?

Comment: Not really, I would have done that if I needed the buttons to do some more stuff before submitting the form.

Comment: And the OP just confirmed my suspicions.

Comment: No, no - I haven't done anything of the sort yet.  I'm just asking whether there's a way around.  Prash responded to my question.

Comment: Sorry about that, @NullUserException is right :) I've amended my answer a little.